# How to call an terraform module in a loop?

Tags: terraform

How can I put the module call in a loop and pass the items of a list to the module calls?
I tried using count and count.index but it failed due to conflict in module name. Module name must be unique.

Comment: Please update the question with the code you currently have.

Answer (score 1):

Try using for_each. I recently faced a similar challenge, and for_each worked better for me than count.

https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each

Example usage from the documentation:

```
module "bucket" {
  for_each = toset(["assets", "media"])
  source   = "./publish_bucket"
  name     = "${each.key}_bucket"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Terraform has a declarative language and so it doesn't exactly have "loops" in the sense you might be familiar with in imperative programming languages.

However, it does have the possibility of declaring multiple instances of a resource or module using a single `resource` or `module` block, with two different variants:

- [`for_each`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each) declares one instance of the resource or module for each element of a map value or a set of strings value. In this case the instances will be tracked using the keys from the provided map or the elements of the provided set.
- [`count`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/count) declares a particular number of instances that should be declared without requiring any association with elements in another collection. In this case the instances will be tracked just with numeric indices, similar to elements of a list.

Here's a contrived example of using `for_each` with a `module` block:

```
variable "example" {
  type = map(object({
    thing_type = string
  }))
}

module "example" {
  source   = "./modules/example"
  for_each = var.example

  thing_type = each.value.thing_type
}
```

If you set `var.example` to the following value...

```
{
  "a" = {
    thing_type = "foo"
  }
  "b" = {
    thing_type = "bar"
  }
}
```

...then this would declare two instances of the module:

- `module.example["a"]` with `thing_type = "foo"`
- `module.example["b"]` with `thing_type = "bar"`

Notice that `["a"]` and `["b"]` become part of the unique addresses of the instances of the module, and are therefore also part of the unique addresses for any resources declared inside the module. If you added a new element `"c"` to the map later then that would declare an additional instance of the module, but if you instead changed the `thing_type` of the existing element `"b"` then Terraform would understand that as changing the configuration for the module instance that already exists, rather than declaring a new one.